# Easycomplete Datagridviewcombobox column winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox, datagridviewcombobox

I am trying to create a datagridComboBoxcolumn in winforms with Suggestions Based on Loose Character Search similar to [Easycomplete combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/755707/ComboBox-with-Suggestions-Based-on-Loose-Character). but I want this as Datagridview combobox.

I have created a grid with Datagridviewcombobox column and used autocomplete but it will search only from first characters. I want loose search. I used

```
 private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control is DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)
            {
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
                ((ComboBox)e.Control).AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            } 
}
```

Please provide me a solution to create this type of datagridviewcombobox.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to create a custom `DataGridiVew` control. This is not a one line code or not a single class code. you have to make several classes for that.

```
public class MyDgv : DataGridView
{
    ....    
}
```

And also create some classes like `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`, `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`, `DataGridViewEditingComboBoxControl`

There is a tutorial how to create custom column in datagridview on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730882(v=vs.80).aspx)